# Popup positioning issue in OpenLayers 2.10

Tags: openlayers-2

We were using OpenLayers 2.7 before and everything was working fine.
Then we decided to upgrade our system to use OpenLayers 2.10.

We have popup positioning issue with this new version. The popup is getting displayed away from the actual marker. It is working fine if I roll back to use OpenLayers 2.7.

I can not insert a snap here but you can have a look at the examples below. Ref. http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.10/examples/popupMatrix.html

I guess there is not an integration issue in my system/code as it's working fine with OpenLayers 2.7. Ref. http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.7/examples/popupMatrix.html

I checked it with all browsers, the behavior is same for all.

Comment: I have checked the live samples from my browser too.. I suppose this is a bug which has been shown as fixed although it is not...

Answer (score 1):

Testing the release URLs you gave, both work in my browser. Since you claim that they don't work in your application, can you clarify: do they not work in the unpacked release examples either? If this is the case, you'll need to be more clear about what browser, etc. you're using, since this isn't the case for me.

Did you update your img/ directory when you updated OpenLayers? In 2.10, the popup image got bigger -- which means that unless you updated the cloud-popup-relative.png image, it will be displaced from where it should be according to its positioning.

(Also: Always update your resources with your version of OpenLayers!)

Comment: Thank you Christopher Schmidt for replying, but Actually i am just checking the Examples online from the site given by Open Layers and facing this issue there too. I checked in multiple browsers and multiple computers even and facing the same problem.

I also checked that my all resources already upgraded to 2.10.


Can anyone check and confirm the same behavior in above examples?



Thank you,
Nilesh Thakkar

Answer (score 0):

I have checked the live samples from my browser too.. I suppose this is a bug which has been shown as fixed in Open Layers although it is not...

Comment: Hi Jibu,

Thank you for your reply. Its bug - http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/ticket/2870

Thanks,
Nilesh Thakkar